# How can I reference to a variable or const in documentation in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to link to a variable/const in objective-c documentation like javadoc? so for example,

```
/**
    This is an {@link #example} javadoc
*/
```

will produce something like `This is an example javadoc`, where `example` will be a hyperlink to the actual variable. All the examples I've found are pretty organized objective-c doc which has no inline reference link.

Comment: Control Command Click on any symbol to jump to its declaration.

Comment: I want to write a doc to the method